# Magento 2: After placing order it is take too much time to redirect to order success page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I'm developing `single store magento` site. In checkout process i'm using `2 payment method` those are `paypal` and `eway`. And my only shipping method is `flat rate method`.

When I go to checkout page all working properly but `after placing order` user have to `wait 3 or 4 minutes` to redirect to order `success page`.

**Please Help me to reduce this time**. Much appreciated you help, Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Do you have any modules that hook into the order place events?

Comment: I am putty that any custom module  or some custom code is creating this issue.

Comment: @Rian there is no such module

Comment: are u sure? which magenot version ae you using?

Comment: @Rian version 2.1.7  i'm using this theme https://themeforest.net/item/porto-ultimate-responsive-magento-theme/9725864 i don't know are there any hook from theme how can i find that

Comment: That page doesn't show anything particular related to the success page or something social. But there's only so many reasons this would happen and honestly, 90% of the time it comes down to a module that integrates into your order place or order save events.

You can try searching for `sales_order_place_after` in your `app/code/community` and `app/code/local` folders. But it might be looking at other things, so if you don't find anything that wont mean that isn't it.

Comment: I am having the same issue right now... 2-3 minutes until the success page shows up. There is no third party module installed.

Comment: I changed my hosting provider now it's loading fast

Answer (score 0):

I Think it's some issue with my server (hosting provider). I have changed my hosting now it's loading fast.